# What do the icons mean in the Find Symbol Results window in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

What do the various icons mean next to the matches found in the Find Symbol Results window? There's a question mark one, a round one looking a little like a no entry sign and one that looks like goto source (this is next to the actual match found).

[image: Find Symbol Results]

Note: To do this symbol search I right click on a variable to get the context menu up then select "Find All References".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The different symbols means different type of references, e.g. declarations, read references, write references, comment and string hits, unknown/guess hits.

The question mark symbolizes unknown/guess hits and the no entry sign is for variables that match by name, but are hidden in their scope by another variable with the same name. The third, "go to source" icon is the read / write reference symbol.

> [image: Unknown/guess] Unknown/Guess hit
>
> [image: Matched but hidden] Matches by name but is hidden in current
>   scope by another symbol
>
> [image: Read/write reference] Read/write reference symbol

Unfortunately I did not find any documentation about the topic, you have to experiment.

Comment: In practice:  The "no entry" symbol matches things references that have the same name, but are confirmed not to be valid references.  (e.g. identically named symbols in other classes)  The "?" generally matches things that aren't actual references to anything - comments, string literals, and some more complex stuff it can't parse, code that is inactive due to preprocessor directives, things in macros, etc.  The "Read/Write" symbol means a confirmed match.  These are the only ones I usually care about.  (I wish there were a way to get rid of the rest...)

Comment: It would be nice if they differentiated read references from write references.

Comment: One example of the "no entry" is that: when "find reference" to a function, for example, foo(), it may find functions in other classes that has the signature foo(Param p1).  I think though function name is the same but the other has parameters, so that is not a "valid" reference.